# How to debug custom kernel with GDB and QEMU

Tags: c++, assembly, gdb, kernel, qemu

I have a simple project which comes to be a very very simple kernel. I have some issues with the code and tried to debug it using `GDB`. Here's the first problem the code is not an executable to be started and debugged in the `GDB`.

After, I tried to debug via QEMU, but since I archived my codes into `.iso` to be able to run it on QEMU. When I tried to set breakpoint in the source file (e.g. main function of `kernel.cpp`) `gdb` said that

> No symbol table is loaded.  Use the "file" command.
>   Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load? (y or [n])

After I say yes, run the program - no breakpoints met.

I tried to google, but only things I find references to "How to debug linux kernel with gdb and qemu" and I couldn't find a way to adapt these suggestions with the "kernel" I have.

Here is my code

`kernel.cpp`

```
void printf(const char *string)`
{
    volatile unsigned char *vmem = (volatile unsigned char *)0xb8000;
    vmem[0] = 0x2f;
    vmem[1] = 0x4b;
    vmem[2] = 0x2f;
    vmem[3] = 0x4f;
}

extern "C" void kernelMain()
{
    printf("Hello world");
    while(1);
}
```

`loader.s`

```
section .multiboot
header_start:
    dd 0xe85250d6
    dd 0
    dd header_end - header_start
    dd 0x100000000 - (0xe85250d6 + 0 + (header_end - header_start))
    dw 0
    dw 0
    dd 8
header_end:

global start
global printf

extern kernelMain

section .text
bits 32
start:
    call kernelMain
    hlt

_loop:
    jmp _loop
```

`linker.ld`

```
ENTRY(start)
OUTPUT_FORMAT("elf64-x86-64")
OUTPUT_ARCH(i386:x86-64)

SECTIONS {
    . = 1M;

    .boot :
    {
        *(.multiboot)
    }

    .text ALIGN(4k):
    {
        *(.text)
    }

    .bss :
    {
        *(.bss)
    }

    .data :
    {
        *(.data)
    }

    .rodata : 
    {
        *(.rodata)
    }

    /DISCARD/ :
    {
        *(.fini_array*)
        *(.note.*)
        *(.eh_frame*)
        *(.comment)
    }
}
```

and finally
`makefile`

```
GXXPARAMS = -m64 -march=x86-64 -fno-use-cxa-atexit -nostdlib -fno-builtin -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -fno-leading-underscore -g

objects = kernel.o loader.o 

.PHONY : all clean pack deploy target

target : clean all pack

all : os.bin

%.o : %.cpp
    gcc -c $(GXXPARAMS) -o $@ $<

%.o : %.s
    nasm -felf64 -o $@ $<

os.bin : $(objects)
    ld -n -T linker.ld -o $@ $^

clean :
    rm -fr *.o *.iso *.bin

pack : all
    cp os.bin iso_tmp/boot/
    grub-mkrescue -o os.iso iso_tmp/

deploy : pack
    qemu-system-x86_64 -cdrom os.iso
```

### UPDATE

In a response to @Michael Petch's question in comments - here's the `GDB` invoking command line

```
gdb qemu-system-x86_64
```

after `GDB` started, I write

```
b kernel.cpp:main
```

then `y` then

```
r -cdrom os.iso
```

Comment: _"failed to set breakpoints"_ is not a good problem description. Describe what exactly you have done and any error messages.

Comment: There is a debugger in which you can debug kernel applications named "KDBG" try that

Comment: Are you aware that you can't properly run 64-bit code while in 32-bit protected mode? Multiboot doesn't put you in 64-bit long mode. It takes you as far as 32-bit protected mode with a flat memory model. You have to code the switch into long mode yourself. There is info here: https://wiki.osdev.org/Setting_Up_Long_Mode . I'd expect the code that prints may not output what you want as a consequence. THis of course doesn't answer your actual question, but it is a heads up to you.

Comment: As for debugging you give a lot of info but haven't actually mentioned how you launch QEMU and GDB to debug. What are the command line parameters you are using to do it?

Comment: For attaching GDB, have you tried the instructions at https://wiki.osdev.org/How_Do_I_Use_A_Debugger_With_My_OS#Use_GDB_with_QEMU ? If you cannot get that to work please show what you tried so we can spot errors.

Comment: FYI, you might want to use BOCHS instead of QEMU.  I've heard BOCHS's built-in debugger is good for early-boot debugging because it understands x86 modes and segmentation, and has helpers for decoding GDT / LDT.

Comment: @vishal: `kdbg` is a KDE front-end for regular GDB.  kgdb is the *Linux* kernel's built-in debugger.  Neither of those are any help; kgdb only exists if the kernel implements debugging hooks.  The OP is using QEMU's GDB-remote support to attach to the virtual machine running the kernel; that doesn't require the kernel itself to know anything about it or have a debugger built-in.

Comment: @MichaelPetch can you please check the updated question?

Comment: You're debugging QEMU itself, not the guest machine it's emulating.  Google how to attach to QEMU as a GDB remote.

Comment: @PeterCordes I understand, but thought that while the QEMU uses my generated binaries maybe I will be able to debug them.

Comment: @Botje Thanks for your link. It helped me. I was able to enter into debug mode.